# Forwarding a subdomain to main domain using Godaddy

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain, godaddy

I have current blog, which was hosted on Tumblr at http://blog.ryanhayes.net.  I'm moving it over to http://ryanhayes.net, and have all the 301 redirects set up for the blog entries to map to my new blog, which is hosted using Godaddy (domain included).  When I try to set up a subdomain forward, I'm greeted with a nice 403 Forbidden response (as of this writing, you can see it at http://blog.ryanhayes.net.  When I try to ping both the subdomain and domain, they point to the same IP address, so I know blog subdomain has at least switched over to point to the same content.  I don't really understand why I would get a 403 Forbidden on the same content that I can see perfectly fine via another domain.

Currently, I have a **CNAME of blog pointing to @**, which is how "www" is set up to forward, so I'm assuming it would do the same thing.

My question is what is the proper way to set up my DNS to make the blog subdomain forward to my main domain (301) using the GoDaddy DNS manager?

Bonus: What is the background on why I am getting a 403 error the current way?

---

### Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

### UPDATE 12/7/2010

Error on site has been fixed, you can no longer view it from my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is right. Just give it some time to propagate. FYI, I am correctly redirected to your parent domain from the subdomain now, without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted worked (no 403). I'm guessing it may not have propigated for you yet. Did you have an index file ready in the directory? I usually only get a 403 if I'm trying to look in something like "/images/" where there's no index.xxx file and I have Apache set to NOT allow directory contents to display.